# main menu disappears only on home page

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I have a site online [engcorrect.net](http://engcorrect.net) and for some reason my menu on my homepage disappears. On all other pages, it shows. The weird thing is that on my localhost (local machine) it shows correctly but not on the production site and it also shows if I use private browsing. What am I missing here? I am using Drupal 7 and bootstrap 3 theme with a subtheme called paper.

There is a css line that I cannot allocate:

```
body.front ul.menu { display:none;}
```

The inspector shows that it originates from engcorrect.net:1 where is that and who set it? 
[image: small screen shot of the css that I see]

resizing doesn't fix the issue either.
Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It's resolved. I cleared the browsers cache in Safari under: Preferences/Privacy/Manage Website Data and there I searched for my site name, selected it and hit "remove all". Therefore I presume it was my Safari browser's cache.